# Cloud Video Intelligence API, permission for role?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, roles

We recently moved to restrict our roles for developers and others accessing the API including other API members for security reasons.

When creating a custom role we cannot find the permission for Cloud Video Intelligence API?

Tried

```
- videointelligence.videos.annotate
- videointelligence.projects.locations.operations.list
- videointelligence.projects.locations.operations.get
- videointelligence.projects.locations.operations.delete
- videointelligence.projects.locations.operations.cancel
- videointelligence.operations.projects.locations.operations.get
- videointelligence.operations.projects.locations.operations.delete
- videointelligence.operations.projects.locations.operations.cancel
```

I get the following error

```
// Command ran
gcloud --project=apple iam roles update basic_api --file=./role-definition.yaml

// Error
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Permission videointelligence.operations.projects.locations.operations.get is not valid.
```

Now, looking around I cannot find these permissions ANYWHERE..

Comment: By inheritance of the legacy, many AI product does not require role to be used, only the API activated on the project. The main reason of that is the confidentiality: there is no confidentiality to use a public model, same for Google Maps, Translate or other. The authentication here (by OAuth token or by API Key) is only to know who will pay for the request.

So, the simple answer to your question is: you can't!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that's simply not true. Every service/api/tool in GCloud has a permission otherwise the entire platform would be insecure and it would defeat the purpose of IAM and adding other users... I got the permission to work by enabled "visionai.[multiple]" permissions in the role.

Comment: Hmmmmm, true for this one, maybe more recent. Not the case for speech to text for instance.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere GCP uses the same permissions url structures under the hood, so everything is linked to a permission; it's how they know what billing works where and what is enabled. Where are you getting this info from exactly? Or is it just guesses..

Comment: In fact, the simple role Service Usage Consumer allows any service account, and user to consume the API on the project, included the speech to text API. There is no strict role for this service, a simple project access is enough for consuming the API.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by enabling.

`visionai.[multiple]"` permissions in the role.

[image]

Shame on Google for making this so difficuit to find, I had to literally guess.